# why does hello world app take 10 seconds to load on iphone xcode 4.1?

Tags: iphone, optimization, build, loading

I want to optimize the loading time of my app because when i connect my iphone and build on it, my app takes 15 seconds to load.  So i first started a "hello world" app, where i just make a view-based app then add a label to the xib "hello world", leaving the viewDidLoad empty

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    //empty
}
```

but even that takes 10 seconds to load.  am i missing a build configuration or something?

Using xcode 4.1, and my app is 15 mb, that is acceptable, right?

I also get a warning that might contribute to the slow time

warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J2)/Symbols/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader (file not found).
warning: No copy of AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal, remember that your app is being debugged on your Mac.
If instead of running your app from XCode, you open it directly from your iPhone (just tapping on the icon) you will notice that the load time is much shorter.

Comment: from this [blog](http://www.dragthing.com/blog/2009/07/how-to-make-your-iphone-app-launch-faster/), the guy was able to check his NSLogs and use his instruments to see what was going on in his app as it loaded.  If i open it directly from my iphone, i won't have access to this, right?

Comment: You can do it on the device if you run the app from XCode in debug mode, and set the run target to a plugged in device.

Comment: No, your app cannot be inspected through Instruments if its run directly on the device.